# Mapping data frame descriptions based on values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to generate a mapping dataframe with each unique code and a description I want prioritised, but need to do it based off a set of prioritisation options. So for example the starting dataframe might look like this:

```
            Filename  TB  Period  Company           Code Desc.  Amount
0     3 - Foxtrot...    Prior TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1000    98     100
1     3 - Foxtrot...    Prior TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1000     7     200
2     3 - Foxtrot...  Opening TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1000    ZX    -100
3     3 - Foxtrot...  Closing TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1000    29    -200
4     3 - Foxtrot...    Prior TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1001    BA     100
5     3 - Foxtrot...  Opening TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1001     9     200
6     3 - Foxtrot...  Closing TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1001   ARC    -100
7     3 - Foxtrot...  Closing TB  FOXTROT  FOXTROT__1001    86    -200
```

The options I have for prioritisation of descriptions are:

1. Firstly to search for viable options in each Period, so for example Closing first, then if not found Opening, then if not found Prior.
2. If multiple descriptions are in the prioritised period, prioritise either longest or first instance.

So for example, if I wanted prioritisation of Closing, then Opening, then Prior, with longest string, I should get a mapping dataframe that looks like this:

```
         Code New Desc.
FOXTROT__1000        29
FOXTROT__1001       ARC
```

Just for context, I have a fairly simple way to do all this in tkinter, but its dependent on generating a GUI of inconsistent codes and comboboxes of their descriptions, which is then used to generate a mapping dataframe.

The issue is that for large volumes (>1000 up to 30,000 inconsistent codes), it becomes impractical to generate a GUI, so for large volumes I need this as a way to auto-generate the mapping dataframe directly from the initial data whilst circumventing tkinter entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as df
#Create a new column which shows the hierarchy given the value of Period
df['NewFilterColumn'] = np.where(  df['Period'] == 'Closing', 1,
                                   np.where(df['Period'] == 'Opening', 2,
                                       np.where(df['Period'] == 'Prior', 3, None
                                               )
                                       )
                                  )
df = df.sort_values(by = ['NewFilterColumn', 'Code','New Desc.'], ascending = True, axis = 0)
```